# Pattern to extract text java

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I am extracting lines of text in Java and then identifying certain values within the text. I need to create two getters to obtain them (as seen in Example 1 and 2).

How to extract string between characters?

First example

`<element>` or  `<element text="">`

with the desired outcome being the word element.

Second example

`<element>VALUE</element>`

with the desired outcome being the word VALUE.
I would guess the best way would be pattern matching?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to parse XML. In that case, a naive "extract everything between two characters" won't work well - you'll need an XML parser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2970947

Comment: What if your first example is followed by `x</element>`? Would you still want `element` or `x`?

Comment: @rustyx I would still like element

Comment: @PrStu01 Is your text in XML format or these tags occur randomly in text which is read?